# Neural Network Backpropagation

Tags: neural-network

I am trying to understand the error backpropagation algorithm to be used in Artificial Neural Networks.

As far as I understand, each neuron has as an output the result of a sigmoid function, which takes as parameter the sum of the product of each weight/input pair plus a "bias" value.

Once the total error of the network is calculated, the derivative of the error with respect to the various weights can be used to find "local minimum" of the error function. These should be the weights where the error is minimum.

However, points where the derivative is zero could also in theory be local maximums... How can I solve this problem?

Cheers :)

Comment: There are various approaches to reducing the local minimum problem. [Here](http://www.paper.edu.cn/scholar/downpaper/lvjiancheng114141-201110-3) is a paper which can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neural network itself couldn't free from the local minimum problem.
So we need additional techniques.

One easy way to reduce the local minimum problem is using momentum. (but, this is not the holy grail)
update weights using historical movement of delta (such as moving average) will be useful.
E.g if in the certain epoch, delta was -1, but the recent delta history was +1, +2, +4, +2.
And we defined the MA size 5. then the actual delta in this epoch will be (+1 +2 +4 +2 -1)/5 = +1.6

Maybe, if you use exponential decaying function to the moving window weight, this momentum approach shows more improved result.

Comment: By local minimum problem you mean the one I outlined above? Sorry, I'm kind of new to neural networks and am self-teaching them :)

Comment: Yes, it's all about finding a local minimum of the error, i.e. you update the weights looking for the error to decrease, but often it increases again. If the algorithm stops there, you might be caught in a _somewhat good_ combination of weights, though not the best of all combinations ever. That's why the mentionend _momentum_ might help: It could make the algorithm search further _even though_ the error still increases a bit.